# Mongoid relationship gives "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)" error

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, sinatra, mongoid

I'm migrating from mongo_mapper to mongoid in Sinatra, and I keep getting this "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)" error in my tests when there is a relationship with a custom relation name, which I'm really stuck on.

I have the following setup:

### Models

```
class Idea
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :text, type: String

  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  has_many :ideas
end
```

### Factories

```
Factory.define :idea do |f|
  f.sequence(:text) { |n| "Idea #{n}" }
  f.association :author, :factory => :user
end

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "Name #{n}" }
end
```

### Spec

```
describe "Something" do
  before do
    Factory(:idea) # <-- This fails
  end

  # ...
end
```

Am I doing something stupid? Left something out? I tried using `inverse_of`, but that didn't seem to fix it either. The equivalent was working fine in mongo_mapper, so I feel like it's some syntactic thing I am doing wrong in mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was me being stupid. I had a hack method `User#ideas` for something previously, and that was clashing with how mongoid was hooking things up (for some reason it was needed in mongo_mapper)